# Android Google Maps save Location

Tags: android, google-maps, save, load

i wanna try to make something like a ParkYourCar App... When i click the Button, my Location should be saved, on button click google maps layout will start and load my koords,when thats done it should make a marker there. Is it possible to save the koords in a text file, in the first layout and load it inot the second layout which is google maps ? and if its possible... How can i do it?

Tried it with Inputstreamreader and so on ... but than my app chrashed :/

thx for reading and replying :)

I got an Class for the first Layout where you can click a button :

```
public class ParkMyCarActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button ParkMyCarButton;
private  Button LoadMyCarButton;
String koordsFileLat = "koordsLat.txt";
String koordsFileLong = "koordsLong.txt";


String koordsLat;
String koordsLong;


private GoogleMap mMap;




//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_park_my_car);

    LoadMyCarButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_LoadMyCar);

    ParkMyCarButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ParkMyCar);
    ParkMyCarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


        @Override

        public void onClick(View ParkMyCar) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ParkMyCarActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));

            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            double Latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double Longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

             koordsLat = String.valueOf(Latitude);
             koordsLong = String.valueOf(Longitude);


        }




    });
```

And the google maps layout :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;


double latitude2 = 51.844188;

double longitude2 = 8.301594;

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest myLocationRequest;

static final LatLng florakoords = new LatLng(51.844188,8.301594);

String savedKoordsLat;
String savedKoordsLong;









@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // Macht andere GooglePlayServices einfacher zu benutzen
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Baut das LocationRequest objekt
    myLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in millisekunden
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in millisekunden
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}





private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {

        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}








private void setUpMap() {


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

    // Erlaubt google maps meine Location zu nutzen
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Ist dazu da das LocationManager aus getSystemService "importiert" wird wofür LocationManager da ist keine ahnung ...
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider (Braucht man um später seine Location zu bestimmen)
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider (Ein string mit dem namen provider wird erschaffen, per LocationManager.getBestProvider wird der Name des providers wiedergegeben, der am besten zu criteria passt ... braucht man auch um seine  LETZTE Location herauszufinden)
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location (Der finala part mit dem mann seine Location bekommt)
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type (hiermit setzte ich den Kartentyp)
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location (Bekommtden Breitengrad meiner Position aus myLocation)
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longtitude of the current location (Bekomme den Längengrad meiner Position aus myLocation)
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location (Latlng speichert die Längengrade und Breitengrade als Koordinaten)
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map (Zeigt die jetzige Location in einer "animation")
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map (Zoomt zu unserer Position, Erschafft danach einen Marker an unserer Position mit der Nachricht "Du bist hier")
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

    // macht nichts ausser Ein Meldungsfenster zu öffnen ...

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Made by Lars Matthäus").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();



    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(florakoords));





}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// Ist dazuda, um meine position zu ubdaten

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

    Marker flora = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(florakoords)
            .title("Castle")
            .alpha(0.7f));





    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());


    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)).setSnippet("Ich bin hier");

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    double entfernung = vergleicheDistanz(currentLatitude,currentLongitude, latitude2,longitude2);


    //Rundet Entfernung
    entfernung = Math.round(100.0 * entfernung)/100.0;

    String entfernungString = String.valueOf(entfernung);

    flora.setSnippet(entfernungString);
    flora.showInfoWindow();




    if (entfernung <= 200.0){


        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Noch 200 Meter bis zum Auto!").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();


    }

    else {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Über 200 meter bis zum Auto").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();

    }

}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public static float vergleicheDistanz(double latitude, double longitude, double latitude2, double longitude2) {


    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(latitude);
    locationA.setLongitude(longitude);

    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(latitude2);
    locationB.setLongitude(longitude2);

    float distanz = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

    return distanz;
}





@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    handleNewLocation(location);
}





@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}





@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}





@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}





@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Location Service Erfolgreich");

    //Fragt die letzte Location ab
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient ,myLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);}
}







@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Location Service gestoppt. Bitte neu starten");
}





@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Comment: Try use SharedPreferences to save location.

Comment: @EliaszKubala hmm i could try it, but will it also save my position,when i close the app and open again?

Comment: @genar yes, it will, its local data storage that isn't affected by reboots.

Comment: k thx :) could you help me with an other problem now ? When the map activity launch.. it instantly chrashes, but only if i use .getLatitude or .getlonitude ...Heres my code

Answer (score 0):

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.


private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest myLocationRequest;
public static final String TAG = GoogleMapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

LocationListener listener;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();



    // Macht andere GooglePlayServices einfacher zu benutzen
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Baut das LocationRequest objekt
    myLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in millisekunden
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in millisekunden
}










@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

















private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}










private void setUpMap() {

    // Erlaubt google maps meine Location zu nutzen
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Ist dazu da das LocationManager aus getSystemService "importiert" wird wofür LocationManager da ist keine ahnung ...
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider (Braucht man um später seine Location zu bestimmen)
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location == null) {
        // request location update!!
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

    }
    else {

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();


    }





    // Show the current location in Google Map (Zeigt die jetzige Location in einer "animation")

    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map (Zoomt zu unserer Position, Erschafft danach einen Marker an unserer Position mit der Nachricht "Du bist hier")
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));


}














@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}